# What does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k a_{n,k}$ exists almost surely for each $n$, actually mean?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, terminology, definition

> Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k a_{n,k}$ exists almost surely for each $n$.

Is it that $P\bigg(\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_ka_{n,k}<\infty\bigg)=1$?

In this case $X_k$ is a sequence of random variables and $a_{n,k}$ are elements of a regular matrix.

I'm just confused on the wording, thanks!

Comment: *Yes.* [More character for comment to appear.]

Comment: @WillM.: In future, try `${}{}{}{}{}$`. It disappears.

Comment: I cannot make sense of the question. There is no $n$ in the statement, only $n_k$  -- how do these symbols relate?

Comment: Actually double apologies, just to be clear, my question is written as $a_{nk}$ but what this must be referring to is $a_{n,k}$ so we're all clear then

Comment: Proving that, for every fixed $n$, $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k a_{n,k}]$ exists would imply the result.

Comment: Ah so showing $E[ |\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k a_{n,k}|] <\infty$ would show that expectation exists. I think I see how to do this now. 

Would you mind clarifying why showing that expectation exists implies the result?

Comment: Is it an argument done with conditional expectations across whether the sum is finite or not?  I just want to be sure what I have in the original question is actually what is implied by "exists almost surely"

Comment: @OGV see Section 2.12 in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value), for instance.